# Лист экземпляров C#

Tags: c#

Здраствуйте, форумчане. Не могу разобраться с листом экземпляров, надеюсь на Вашу помощь.
Используя фабричный метод в программе, не могу разобраться с заполнением листа экземпляром, делаю его публичным, но не могу получить доступ к нему внутри класса.

```
 class Menu
{
    public void menu()
    {
        List<Project> projects = new List<Project>();
       // манипуляции с меню
        switch (menu)
        {
            case 1:
                CreateFunc(new ProjectType());
                break;
    }
    static void CreateFunc(CreateType create)
    {
        create.NewObject();
    }
}
```

Сам фабричный метод:

```
    abstract class CreateType
{
    public abstract ICreate Add();

    public void NewObject()
    {
        var createtype = Add();
        createtype.Adding();
    }
}

class ProjectType : CreateType
{
    public override ICreate Add()
    {
        return new Project();
    }
}
```

И класс из которого нужно данные передать в лист projects:

```
 public interface ICreate
{
    public void Adding();
}

class Project : ICreate
{
    public void Adding()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        string name;
        string language;
        string level;
        // манипуляции по заданию переменных name, language, level
        projects.Add()
    }
}
```

Суть в том, что мне нужно сохранить эти данные, чтобы использовать в классе Меню, буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: 1) Фабричный метод ничего не должен знать в принципе о list. В этом смысл фабричного метода.
2) Метод Adding - в чем его смысловая нагрузка вообще?
3) Вы нигде не сохраняете значения name, language, level.

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно после использования фабричного метода, дальше работать с данными, которые в нем получены

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    class Menu
    {
        public void menu()
        {
            List<Project> projects = new List<Project>();
            // манипуляции с меню
            switch (menu)
            {
                case 1:
                    CreateFunc(new ProjectType());
                    break;
            }

            void CreateFunc(ICreateType create)
            {
                projects.Add(create.Create());
            }
        }
    }

    public interface ICreateType
    {
        public Project Create();
    }

    class ProjectType : ICreateType
    {
        public Project Create()
        {
            return new Project();
        }
    }

    public class Project
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }

        public Project()
        {
            Name = "";
            Language = "";
            Level = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы говорите, что метод NewObject не нужен, а потом используете его в Menu

Comment: Да, не заметил, поправил.

Comment: Но ведь в Adding() должны были происходить действия по изменению тех переменных (ввод пользователя и т.д.), Вы предлагаете мне его в return new Project{ } реализовать?

Comment: Можете сделать конструктор, который будет менять поля. Или тот же метод с входящими параметрами. Или делать в return new, смотря на сколько сложные изменения

Comment: В интерфейсе у меня метод Adding, но в классе Project он не реализуется, судя по тому, что вы в самом верху ответа написали

Comment: А так же в последнем методе, подчеркивает create.Add() и пишет, что нельзя переобразовать ICreate в Project

Comment: Добавил все одним куском. Я описал идею изменений до этого. Теперь можно скопировать все как есть. Добавил все классы и интефейсы.

Comment: Разобрался, благодарю Вас.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105734/discussion-between-vladimir-maksymchuk-and-sergey).